# Laravel4 Multiauth Login

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-4

I am working on laravel Demo application and i am using login authentication for `frontend` and `backend` both are using different tables `users` and `admin` respectively.

To achieved multiauth in laravel 4 i have used https://github.com/ollieread/multiauth library.

Now my problem is i don't know how to handle both-side login authentication. I have followed all the instructions as provided in github. its working fine for me as `frontend` side with `users` table but its not working for admin table for `backend`

I am getting error for backend login.

`Call to undefined method Admin::newQuery()`

Here i am providing my code snippest what i have done so far.

**auth.php**

```
'multi' => array(
            'admin' => array(
                'driver' => 'eloquent',
                'model' => 'Admin'
            ),
            'user' => array(
                'driver' => 'database',
                'table' => 'users'
            )
        )
```

**userController.php** `frontend`

```
public function doLogin() {
        $input = Input::all();
        $credentials = array(
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'password' => $input['password']
        );

        if(Auth::user()->attempt($credentials)){
            return Redirect::intended('/');
        }
        // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
        return Redirect::to('login')->with('error_message', 'Invalid email or password')->withInput();
    }
```

**adminLoginController.php** `backend`

```
public function doLogin() {
        $input = Input::all();
        $credentials = array(
            'username' => $input['username'],
            'password' => $input['password']
        );
        if (Auth::admin()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return Redirect::route('dashboard');
        }
        // authentication failure! lets go back to the login page
        return Redirect::to('admin/')->with('error_meessage', 'Invalid username or password')->withInput();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Instead of this:

```
 'multi' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => 'Admin'
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'users'
        )
    )
```

Use this:

```
    'multi' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'driver' => 'database',
            'model'  => 'Admin',
            'table'  => 'admin'
        ),
        'user' => array(
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model'  => 'User',
            'table'  => 'users'
        )
    )
```